# Python iterating over a datastructure code explanation

Tags: python, dictionary, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I was writing a code in python using ldapsearch and came across this link in [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Active_Directory/Search_for_a_user#Python)

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.example.com")
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

    bind = l.simple_bind_s("me@example.com", "password")

    base = "dc=example, dc=com"
    criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))"
    attributes = ['displayName', 'company']
    result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)

    results = [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]
    print results
finally:
    l.unbind()
```

I am unable to understand this piece of code here `results = [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]`

- I don't see `dn` defined in the above code, so where does it take from?
- What does `isinstance(entry, dict)` do?

When I tries to execute this, I can see that this returns a list of all ldap entries, with its corresponding attributes associated with it. The initial `result` is also returning a list. Can someone please explain what the `results` code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
somelist = [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)] 
translates to 

for entry, dn in result:
   if isinstance(entry, dict): # this checks if entry is of type dictionry
      somelist.append(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you. The break down version helped to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing there is a **list comprehension**.
They are constructs that allow sequences to be built from other sequences.

The reason you do not see `dn` before the list comprehension because it is a placeholder (similar to `item` in a `for item in list` loop).

I'm not an expert on comprehensions, so I've included some links that may help you shed some more light on the matter.

[Tutorial: List Comprehensions](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php)
[Run down of syntax](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html)